Failed to convert elements of SparseTensor(indices=Tensor("DeserializeSparse:0", shape=(None, 2), dtype=int64), values=Tensor
I have mentioned my code below
from tensorflow.keras import layers , models

model = models.Sequential()

    # Convolutional layers
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(48,48,3)))
# model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))

# Flatten layer to transition from convolutional to fully connected layers
model.add(layers.Flatten())

# Fully connected layers
model.add(layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))  # Dropout for regularization
model.add(layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))  # Output layer

model.summary()
model.compile(loss = "sparse_categorical_crossentropy",optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])

i am getting an error while executing
model.fit(X_train,y_train,batch_size=32,epochs = 10)

I verified my input shape as well my ouput shape , but still i got an error message
TypeError: Failed to convert elements of SparseTensor(indices=Tensor("DeserializeSparse:0", shape=(None, 2), dtype=int64), values=Tensor("DeserializeSparse:1", shape=(None,), dtype=int64), dense_shape=Tensor("stack:0", shape=(2,), dtype=int64)) to Tensor. Consider casting elements to a supported type. See https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/dtypes for supported TF dtypes.

Can anyone give me the reason why it is happening , i loaded my data by using open-cv and append it to an list and converted it to an np.array and performed train test split

tensorflow's convolution works on floats and not integers. try  convert your input type to floats

Hi@Prabakaran ,,you are facing an error due to data type or shapes of input ,check that your model shape  is (48,48,3).So it should be 4D array if it is not correct you will face an issue.Check that you put the compatible data type x_train (float32) and Y_train(int64). Check this if you are still facing an issue let me know,Thanks.
